# Изменение типа возвращаемой переменной при использовании декоратора

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, декоратор, типизация

При использовании статической типизации в python столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Ниже привожу код модуля:

```py
from functools import wraps
from timeit import default_timer
import typing

Callable = typing.Callable


def timer(function: Callable) -> Callable:
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> dict:
        ts = default_timer()
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        te = default_timer()
        #
        # !!! Changing function return type !!!
        #
        return {"value": result, "timer": (te - ts) * 1e3}
    return wrapper


@timer
def some_function(x: float) -> float:
    return x*x


def main():
    x = some_function(1.01).get("value")
    t = some_function(1.01).get("timer")
    print("Function returns value {:6.2f} after {:6.2f} ms".format(x, t))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Анализатор кода (я использую IDE PyCharm) убежден, что тип возвращаемого методом `some_function` значения -- `float`, а не `dict`, и ругается на метод `get`.

Между тем, написанный выше код сам по себе работает именно так, как ожидается.

Использую версию `python 3.7.5`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом исправить данную ситуацию. Как изменить тип данных?

Comment: Честно говоря, я бы не сильно заморачивался с анализом типов в pycharm. Как показывает практика, такие проблемы возникают направо и налево. И если решать каждую из них, то приходится либо сильно ограничивать себя в возможностях и избегать нетривиальных способов построения кода, либо писать код "заглушку", пытаясь обмануть типизатор

Comment: Вообще конечно вопрос, насколько синтаксически верно статически типизировать возврат функции, которая будет обернута декоратором?

Comment: Вообще PyCharm правильно ругается: если задекларирован один тип возвращаемого значения, а фактически возвращается другой - значит что-то здесь не так. Как вариант, можно не подменять возвращаемое значение, а сохранять результат замера в объекте-декораторе.

Comment: На самом деле так делать плохо (менять тип возвращаемого значения декоратором), декораторы -> это синтаксический сахар, в идеале мы должны понимать его задачу лишь по названию (при чтении кода), а тут нам получается придется лезть в код декоратора чтобы понять, что у функции поменялся возвращаемый тип

Comment: @Basalex, а вариант: завести внешний стек, и внутри декоратора, не меняя при этом сигнатур и возвращаемых типов методов, заполнять этот стек интересующими значениями -- более удачным был бы?

Comment: @Дмитрий, лучше на самом деле можно еще  вcпомнить, что функция - это объект и можно вообще хранить данные у нее в свойствах

Comment: @insolor tired of this drama Не соглашусь. Применяя декоратор к некоторому имени, мы декларируем **результат** декоратора, а отнюдь не аргумент. Банальный пример - декоратор `classmethod`. Мы же не ожидаем, что после его применения к функции мы будем получать экземпляр класса первым аргументом? Хотя сама функция без этого декоратора декларирует именно такое поведение. Это всё равно что ожидать, что результатом `int(float(1.23))` будет тип `float`.

Comment: Тоже самое и с кодом выше. Если убрать `-> Callable`, то декларируется именно **новый тип результата `dict`** (хотя разумеется это очень странно). Проще говоря декларируется то, что ожидается фактически - и никак иначе. А если бы декоратор возвращал функцию, которая возвращает подкласс `float`? Тоже немного странно, но уже соответствует принципу Лисков. Pycharm это также не распознает. Или распознает, если вместо `@decorator\ndef function(): pass` писать `function = decorator(function)`. И таких косяков предостаточно.

Comment: @Дмитрий для измерения скорости исполнения кода в python есть модуль [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html)

Comment: @Basalex, хранить данные в свойствах, например, модифицируя `__dict__`? Мне кажется это ещё менее читаемым.

Comment: @ Дмитрий, возможно написать function.value = 4 не самый лучший вариант, но все лучше изменения возвращаемого значения

Answer (score 2):

Pycharm, как и любое другой анализатор, постоянно ошибается, и каждый раз это исправлять вряд ли того стоит. Тем не менее, этот код можно переписать так, чтобы и сомнительных идиом не было, и Pycharm всё понимал:

```
import time

class Timer:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.start = time.time()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.elapsed = time.time() - self.start


# ...

with Timer() as t:
    res = some_function()

print("Function returns value {:6.2f} after {:6.2f} ms".format(res, t.elapsed)
```

И кстати, в оригинальной версии функция вызывается два раза.

Comment: `Pycharm, как и любое другой анализатор, постоянно ошибается` - в целом может быть, но в случае кода в вопросе это неоднозначность кода, а не ошибка анализатора.

Comment: Ну да, сомнительная идиома. Но в коде всё однозначно, там всегда возвращается  dict, и таки Pycharm не смог это понять. Бывает.

Comment: Если убрать аннотацию возвращаемого значения у `some_function`, то "внезапно" PyCharm  перестает ругаться на `get`. Так что проблема в данном случае именно в неоднозначных аннотациях.

Comment: Про повторный вызов - согласен, дал маху :) И за идею с классом спасибо!

Comment: @insolor tired of this drama Что толку, что он перестанет ругаться? В любом случае он **неверно** распознает тип декларируемого значения. Убрав `-> float` мы получаем `-> typing.Any`.